# Any reason for multiple parameter constructor in a persistence class?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, reflection

I am working on a Java web application that I inherited that uses Spring and Hibernate. This application contains persistence classes that were automatically generated using hbm2java. Included in these classes were constructors with multiple parameters (as well as your typical default constructor). These non-default constructors are not being directly accessed by any other methods. Nor is there any explicit spring definition for calling these classes, so it appears that it is dead code...

Now I know this question is hideously vague, but would there be any normal reason where Hibernate would normally invoke these constructors through reflection? I know it uses `Class<T>.getInstance()` to invoke the default constructor to create a new instance of the object, but that's about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those are not there because the hibernate will use them.

That type of constructors are often useful when you instantiate and initialize the entity class. Instead of using the default constructor and calling multiple setters, it's easier to use a constructor that takes multiple parameters.

Comment: The problem is that Hibernate can swap parameters on the constructor from one code generation to another. Just happened to me and a co-worker.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your db. Normally hibernate creates constructors for all the columns in your db and then another constructor for all the mandatory fields.

Comment: "hibernate creates constructors"? How?

Comment: If you reverse engineer your entity objects using the hibernate plugin for eclipse they will have mutliple constructors. This is what I assumed 'persistence' classes mean't in the question. As he mentioned it is slightly vague so I took a shot!

Comment: I think it's the plugin that is actually generating those entities by reverse engineering the db tables.

Comment: Im sorry didnt I just say that!

Comment: I'm sorry, by persistence classes I meant the entity classes. The java code for them was auto-generated by hbm2java.